# Why Amazon EC2 was terminated by AutoScaling Group regardless of protection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My Amazon EC2 Instance was terminated by AutoScaling Group regardless of EC2 "terminate protection" and AutoScaling Group Instance "scale In protection".

Is that correct behavior?

Some details:

- EC2 had termination protection enabled
- AutoScaling Group had ScaleIn Protection for this EC2 instance.
- AutoScaling Group Health check was set to ELB.

When application Load balancer detected health issue - EC2 was terminated.

**UPDATE:**

- It was a farm of 2 web servers (windows, IIS) with application load balancer (health check using web page) and auto scaling group (set to maintain at least 2 servers and 10Mb NetworkOut as a target)
- I stopped IIS to emulate health issue *(Actually I turn EC2 to StandBy mode, stopped IIS, updated web site and turned it back to inService with stopped IIS - if it makes sense)*
- Load Balancer detected health issue and excluded instance from target group - *good job!*
- Auto Scaling Group terminated protected EC2

Comment: Please expand upon "When application Load balancer detected health issue" — what was the issue? Was it specifically related to one instance? Or was it just a general scale-in based on workload (rather than a 'health' issue)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it was scale in based on health issue. 
From activity history: Terminating EC2 instance: i-xxx
Cause: instance was taken out of service in response to ELB system health check failure

Comment: Well, it seems that unhealthy instances are by Auto Scaling removed regardless of the _Termination Protection_ and _Sale-In Protection_ settings. Makes sense, since an unhealthy instance is of no use to anybody.

Comment: I thought if you set Termination Protection - then it's protected from been terminated. 
Since it's unhealthy, AutoScale Group could just move this instance into StandBy mode, instead of terminating it - that was my expectation.

Comment: Auto Scaling does not "move" instances. It simply terminates them. There are commands where you can tell Auto Scaling to add/remove instances from a scaling group, but it won't do that on its own.